# Making Cinemachine Main Camera lock to Global Offset instead of Local

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I'm making a golf simulator game and trying to use cinemachine to track the ball through the air. The only issue is when I offset to try and make the camera more realistic, the spinning ball causes the offset to go berserk, spinning the camera along with it. Is there any way to attach the camera to a global offset rather than one that's constantly rotating?

Currently using a standard virtual camera with the following settings: [image: Camera Settings]

Any offset causes it to spin wildly in both aim and body fields!

Also tried adding a free-look camera with the inputs disabled and the same thing happens, [video link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HKeHLhS6P9-3Z243dxJEvn2NpvYz4d7C/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create an empty gameObject name: CameraTarget
2. Place the Golf as a child of the CameraTarget
3. Have the cinemachine follow CameraTarget

Now you can rotate the golf any way you want without affecting the camera.